# Training a TensorFlow-Keras model with extra layer which gets also the labels as input

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I want to train a model which create a features vector for a RGB image (2D array with 3 channels), and using that features vector, a classifier will decide what to do (e.g. person recognition from an image, assign a label by choosing the "closest" pre-trained features vectors (of the people enrolled to the system). To do so I use a categorical cross-entropy. In the training phase I apply categorical softmax on the features vector as an extra layer, and get as output the probability to be in each label or class, then I use the softmax output and the training label to compute the loss.
So, for working or testing, the model receives just one input: the image, and outputs a features vector. While for training the model receives pairs: the image and its label.

I want to train such a model, with pair [image,label] input in the training phase, and [image] input in the testing or working phase.

I use `TensorFlow 2.8` and `Keras 2.8` with `Python 3.9.5`.

The code (with a toy model and some random data):

```
# ==============================================================================
# Imports
# ==============================================================================
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras import layers as tfl
from keras import Model

# ==============================================================================
# Switch case layer, behaves differently for training and testing
# ==============================================================================
class Switch(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        x = tf.identity(inputs)
        if training:
            y = tfl.Input(shape=(2,), name="label")
            output_tensor = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, x)
            return output_tensor
        else:
            output_tensor = tf.identity(x, name="output")
            return output_tensor

# ==============================================================================
# Define model
# ==============================================================================
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(4, 4, 3))
conv = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=2)(inputs)
pooling = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(conv)
feature = keras.layers.Dense(10)(pooling)
outputs = Switch()(feature)
# output = tf.identity(feature)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

# ==============================================================================
# Training data
# ==============================================================================
tf.random.set_seed(42)
x_train = tf.random.normal((5, 4, 4, 3))
y_train = tf.constant([1, 1, 0, 0, 2])

# ==============================================================================
# Train model
# ==============================================================================
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics='accuracy',)
model.fit(
    x=x_train, 
    y=y_train,
    epochs=3,
    verbose='auto',
    shuffle=True,
    initial_epoch=0,
    max_queue_size=10
)
```

The Switch layer is based on: [Is it possible to add different behavior for training and testing in keras Functional API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67078684/is-it-possible-to-add-different-behavior-for-training-and-testing-in-keras-funct)

If I understand correctly, when using model.fit, the model's call is automatically invoked with `training=True`.

However, when I run the model I get the following error:

> TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(),
> dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0',
> description="created by layer 'tf.cast_4'"), an intermediate Keras
> symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering
> custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes,
> or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF
> API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or
> `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic
> Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting
> the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on
> this symbolic input/output.

When I pass:

```
model.fit(
    x=[x_train, y_train], 
    y=y_train,
```

I receive the following error:

> ValueError: Layer "model" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input
> tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None,
> 4, 4, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,)
> dtype=int32>]

The problem is probably due to the Switch layer.

How do I solve it and how I train a model in which the training phase input and output are different than in the working phase (gets image, outputs features vector)?

Comment: The layers and the details of this toy model are not important to the question and were taken from Keras help documentation. You can replace them with other layers, such as conv and dense etc, if tit makes it work.